# fabric js draw overlapping lines

Tags: fabricjs

i just started using fabric js.
I want to show some overlapping lines, when two elements (rectangles for example) are on the same height / within canvas.
What would be the best practice for that?

I do some  snapping between objects like:

```
function onChange(options) {
    options.target.setCoords();
    canvas.forEachObject(function (obj) {
        if (obj === options.target) return;

        if (Math.abs(obj.top - options.target.top) < snapTolerance) {
            options.target.set({
                top: obj.top
            });
    });
}
```

When the snapping occurs, i want to show a line between the snapping objects.

Perhaps someone could post a fiddle?

Kind regards